# Regex that checks for the validity of options, disallowing duplicates

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex to check for the validity of options that are supplied with a command.

Say that `-a`, `-b` and `-c` are valid options. They may be combined, for example as `-ac` or `-abc`. Order doesn't matter, so `-ba` is also valid.
I thought this regex would do the trick:

`^-[abc]{1,3}$`

But it has a downside. This regex also accepts duplicates, i.e. `-abb`.

How do I modify this regex to disallow duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a capture group and a negative lookahead:

```sh
^-((?!.*\1)[abc]){1,3}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tlfsBv/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `-`: Match a `-`
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `(?!.*\1)`: Negative lookahead to make sure we don't have repeat of what we have in capture group #1 anywhere in the input
  - `[abc]`: Match `a` or `b` or `c`
- `){1,3}`: End capture group #1. Repeat this group 1 to 3 times
- `$`: End

Comment: Great and Interesting... I thought `\1` doesn't work because the group 1 is not closed when `\1` gets evaluated, I mean there is no group 1 on that moment. Sir could you elaborate this a bit ?

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary: First time when we haven't captured anything in group 1 then `\1` is non-existent therefore `(?!.*\1)` succeeds. For subsequent captures negative lookahead condition duly works preventing any duplicate match for each letter match.

Comment: So you mean, syntactically regex doesn't complain about referencing the group which is not defined yet(group 1)!. As a programmer's point of view, I thought we can only reference the group which is defined before. something like `(abc)....\1 ` is obviously defined before but in `(ab\1) `, that group is not defined completely.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you can check linked demo. This feature doesn't work in Javascript though but works fine in PCRE, Python, Java, .NET etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could list all the alternatives, but if it is a long character class, you can check that on the right side there is no char that is already captured using a capture group and a backreference.

```
^-(?![abc]*?([abc])[abc]*?\1)[abc]{1,3}$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `-` Match a hyphen
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that at the right is not

  - `[abc]*([abc])[abc]*\1` Match optional chars a, b or c and then capture 1 char. Then check that the captured char does not occur at the right side
- `)` Close lookahead
- `[abc]{1,3}` Match 1-3 times `a` `b` or `c`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/94dQWt/1)

Or a short version using only non whitespace chars, as the character class can only match 3 chars.

```
^-(?!\S*(\S)\S*\1)[abc]{1,3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1tTdRo/1)